# Which factors should I consider when choosing between 2 jobs in 2 different countries?

Tags: united-states, lecturer, australia, associate-professor

I am faced with a dilemma: I just returned from two years trying out a lecturer position at a top Australian university. My US public R1 was generous to grant me a leave of absence to do so.

I am trying to weigh all the pros and cons of each situation before making such a life-changing decision as resigning from one of the two.

I can't "follow my heart" because my children and I have been very happy in both places. Both universities are located in highly desirable locations with nice weather. Both places have cons, also, including an insanely high cost of living in both cities. I am neither from the US nor from Australia.

Right now, it feels scary to resign from a tenured associate professor position in the US for a lecturer one. It feels like a step-down in job security. However, the Aussie institution is a lot more prestigious than the US one. Please help me brainstorm any factor I might not have taken into consideration yet. I am especially keen to hear from people who have experienced a similar move.

Comment: What kind of job security is there at the Aussie job?

Comment: Is it a step-down in job security?  General labor law protections in Australia for permanent jobs (I assume your lecturer job is permanent, not term-limited) are a lot stronger than in the US and might be similar to the protection of tenure (except everyone gets it).

Comment: It is a continuing (permanent) position. I guess it is quite secure. However, it seems that, in the Australian system, people get stuck at the senior lecturer level if they don't obtain any ARC grants and those are nearly impossible to get in my field. The downside of my 2 years there was the incredible amount of time spent applying to these grants - time during which I could have written a book!

Comment: Given that you seem you would be happy at either place, I think this comes down more to personal (and family) preference. Any chance of a dual appointment allowing you to bounce back and forth (harder on the kids though).

Comment: Oh, I have not heard of dual appointments. How do they work? That would be hard to negotiate, I think, but ideal...

Comment: Which location has the better school for your kids? which one has an easier commute.

Comment: @VitaminE: the Aussie school has both. In fact, everything is better in Australia for my kids but the job there seems less secure and is a lot more stressful than my current one. That's why I am torn.